# Printing multiple Dymo labels with Cups

Tags: linux, printing, cups, dymo

I can print a single label using the command `lp -o DymoPrintQuality=Text -o PageSize=w54h144 -o landscape -n 1 -d Dymo400Turbo /tmp/test.txt`.

When I use the command `lp -n 2 -o DymoPrintQuality=Text -o PageSize=w54h144 -o landscape -d Dymo400Turbo /tmp/test.txt` it prints one label, not 2.

I have tested lp with the -n option printing to a non Dymo printer and -n is respected.

lpr also only prints one label.

I have tried with Cups 1.4.3 and Cups 2.1.3, I am using dymo-cups-drivers-1.4.0.5 downloaded from http://www.dymo.com/en-US/dymo-label-sdk-and-cups-drivers-for-linux-dymo-label-sdk-cups-linux-p--1

If anyone has any ideas I would be grateful.

Thanks to Philipp at the http://developers.dymo.com/2012/02/21/announcing-dymo-labelwriterlabelmanager-sdk-1-4-0-for-linux/#comment-84704 the answer is to change *cupsManualCopies: to True in the ppd file.

Comment: If you have the time, please make your edit an actual _answer_ to the question, then you can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to change *cupsManualCopies: to True in the ppd file.

Thanks to Philipp at http://developers.dymo.com/2012/02/21/announcing-dymo-labelwriterlabelmanager-sdk-1-4-0-for-linux/#comment-84704 for this.